# Geometrical problem

Tags: geometry

I have a problem to calculate
At the given picture the line segments AB , AC , FE ,GH , GI are known
I want to calculate the line segment ED
Is this posible ?
Thanks in advance
Nikos[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for many cases:

This gives the relative position $\lambda \in [0,1]$:
$$
\lvert\overline{FE}\rvert 
= (1-\lambda) \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert + \lambda \lvert\overline{GH}\rvert
= \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert + \lambda (\lvert\overline{GH}\rvert - \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert)
$$

If we have a non-zero slope, 
$\lvert\overline{GH}\rvert \ne \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert $ 
we can solve for $\lambda$:
$$
\lambda =
\frac{\lvert\overline{FE}\rvert - \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert}{\lvert\overline{GH}\rvert - \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert}
$$

Then we have
$$
\lvert\overline{FD}\rvert 
= (1-\lambda) \lvert\overline{AC}\rvert + \lambda \lvert\overline{GI}\rvert
$$

insert $\lambda$ and apply
$$
\lvert\overline{ED}\rvert 
= \lvert\overline{FD}\rvert - \lvert\overline{FE}\rvert
$$

to get
$$
\lvert\overline{ED}\rvert =
\lvert\overline{AC}\rvert +
\frac{\lvert\overline{FE}\rvert - \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert}{\lvert\overline{GH}\rvert - \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert}
(\lvert\overline{GI}\rvert- \lvert\overline{AC}\rvert)
- \lvert\overline{FE}\rvert
$$

There is also the boring case:
$$
\lvert\overline{GH}\rvert = \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert
= \lvert\overline{FE}\rvert 
\wedge
\lvert\overline{GI}\rvert = \lvert\overline{AC}\rvert
$$
with solution
$$
\lvert\overline{ED}\rvert 
= \lvert\overline{AC}\rvert -
 \lvert\overline{AB}\rvert
$$

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean that the lengths of the line segments and not their positions are given.

From the [intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) you get

$$\frac{\text{ED} - \text{BC}}{\text{AF}} = \frac{\text{HI} - \text{BC}}{\text{AG}}$$

so

$$\text{ED} = \frac{\text{HI} - \text{BC}}{\text{AG}} \cdot \text{AF} + \text{BC}$$

where ofc HI = GI - GH and BC = AC - AB. BUT with your information, you cannot compute AF nor AG, i.e. there is no way to obtain the $x$-position of the middle and rightmost segments, so I say it is impossible.

Comment: You don't need $AF$ or $AG$, you only need $\frac{AF}{AG},$ which you certainly can compute. (We all appear to be assuming the "vertical" lines are all parallel.)

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for revealing that implicit assumption.

Comment: I thank everybody for the effort

Comment: I don't know the values on the x axis The only known is the values on y axis and the vertical lines are parallel

Answer (score 0):

According to the intercept theorem, it follows that:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{ED - BC}{HI - BC}=\frac{FE - AB}{GH - AB}
\end{align}
$$

To solve for $ED$, you would get:

$$
\begin{align}
ED =\frac{(FE - AB)(HI - BC)}{GH - AB} + BC
\end{align}
$$

I hope this helps..

Comment: I believe that this is the solution cause if FD coincide with AC or FD coincide with GI the formula is true Thanks DrC